# Select all columns from all tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How can I Select all columns from all tables from the DB, like:

```
Select * From *
```

in SQL Server 2008???

The table list it´s very very big, and have so many columns, is it possible to do it without writing the column names?

Or maybe make a select that returns the name of the tables.

Comment: Why would  you want to do this?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense.  What exactly do you expect to get back from such a query?

Comment: If you wanted to inject SQL, that is one of the simpler things you could inject to get back the schema meta data comes to mind. To actually do it requires a statement using system views etc, but you see what I mean.

Comment: Well, don't really know, I was asked to do this... Actually they need the data In Excel, but it's table by table, so I need to automate the query...

Comment: This may help. http://kb.softescu.ro/programming/p-tsql/select-all-columns-from-all-tables-in-the-database/

Comment: legitimate reason for wanting this: i want to do this because I am clearing out a database to start again with a new client. it has some data i want to keep, and a lot to delete. i don't want to mess about with scripts to create a clean instance so this is a easy way to ensure i have deleted everything correctly

Comment: @DavidBasarab old question but I thought I'd give my reason for wanting this: I have a test that is failing if I run a specific test before it, even though every test is within a transaction and "should" be rolled back when finishing no matter the result. This makes me wanting an easy way to check the content of the whole database before and after each test to see if I can figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This SQL will do this...

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVarChar(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG('SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ';', CHAR(13))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: how would you print a `table_name` for each result?

Comment: @Kuncevic, If you want to include the table name in each resultset, just add it into the @@SQL (Replace the double "at" signs with a single one):  SELECT @@SQL = @@SQL + 'SELECT ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TableName, * FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME + ']' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Comment: ahh I was doing exactly same thing but using 1 single quote `' + TABLE_NAME + '` - didn't work. instead of using 3 `''' + TABLE_NAME + '''`  - that works.

Answer (score 16):

Try this, works fine

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

then you could add

```
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE ''
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID where t.name = 'ProductItem'  AND C.name like '%retail%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to retrieve the name of all columns from [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)
It is possible to retrieve the name of all table from [sys.tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx)

But is impossible to retrieve all the data from all the tables. As soon as more than one table is involved in a query, a JOIN is necessary. Unless join conditions are provided, tables are joined as full Cartesian product, meaning each row from each table is matched with each row from ll other tables. Such a query as you request would produce for 10 tables with 10 records each no less than 10e10 records, ie. 100 billion records. I'm sure you don't want this.

Perhaps if you explain what you *what* to achieve, not *how*, we can help better.

To select * from each table, one after another, you can use the undocumented but well known sp_msforeachtable:

```
sp_msforeachtable 'select  * from ?'
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2016 Management Studio ( Version: 13.0.15900.1), to get all column names in a specified table, below is the syntax:

```
   **Select name from [YourDatabaseName].[sys].[all_columns] 
   where object_id=(Select object_id from [YourDatabaseName].[sys].[tables] 
   where name='YourTableName')**
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to send to Excel, I would suggest you use the export wizard and simply select all the tables there. In the object browser, put your cursor on the database name and right click. Chose Tasks - Export Data and follow the wizard. WHy anyone would want an entire database in Excel is beyond me, but that's the best way. If you need to do it more than once you can save the export in an SSIS package.