# Find all tables name where value matched

Tags: sql

I want to get list of all table names where a specific value is matched within all tables and all its columns. I already tried something like bellow but seems sql query is not correct. Any idea how I can do this?

```
select * from table where value='john@example.com'
```

I need this query for MS SQL server. Maybe its a bad idea to run such big query but this will be helpful to understand a development version of non relational database.

Comment: you want from one column of one table or all table and columns in database

Comment: all table and columns in database. The idea is to understand where this specific value is being saved and its connected with.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: No, It is Microsoft SQL server 2019 but previous developer not created any relation between tables & it contains hundreds of tables so its super hard to understand where specific data is saved.

Comment: You need to get all tables and column from inforamation_schema and execute a dynamic query to figure this out I think. You can refer almost similar scenario in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51626453/4923740

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534147/select-all-columns-from-all-tables-in-sql-server-2008